# How to take a pathname string with wildcards and resolve the glob with pathlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob, pathlib

If I'm given a path as a string, such as "~/pythoncode/*.py" what is the best way to glob it in `pathlib`?

Using pathlib, there is a way of appending to a path using a glob:

```
p = pathlib.Path('~/pythoncode/').expanduser().glob('*.py')
```

but this, for example, does not work because the user isn't expanded:

```
p = pathlib.Path().glob('~/pythoncode/*.py')
```

and this is generates an exception because I'm providing no arguments to `glob()`:

```
p = pathlib.Path('~/pythoncode/*.py').expanduser().glob()
```

Is there a way to do this in `pathlib`, or must I parse the string first?

Comment: I think your question answers itself, but I could be wrong

Comment: Look into `PurePath.parts`

Comment: I believe `os.path.expanduser()` is a no-op passthrough if there is nothing to expand, so you might be able to do something like `Path().glob(os.path.expanduser('~/pythoncode/*.py'))`

Comment: @jedwards: `NotImplementedError: Non-relative patterns are unsupported`

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I think it only answers itself if I'm not overlooking something-- which seemed likely with my lack of experience with this library.  `pathlib` is quite complete, I was hoping that with the right call order it had a way of more closely mimicking the shell and doing a full expansion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're starting from the string `"~/pythoncode/*.py"` and you'd like to expand and glob, you will need to split the path first. Luckily pathlib provides `.name` and `.parent` to help [you out](https://docs.python.org/3/lirary/pathlib.html#correspondence-to-tools-in-the-os-module):

```
def expandpath(path_pattern) -> Iterable[Path]:
    p = Path(path_pattern)
    return Path(p.parent).expanduser().glob(p.name)

expandpath("~/pythonpath/*.py")
```

Note this simple solution will only work when only the `name` includes a glob, it will not work with globs in other parts of the path, like: `~/python*/*.py`. A more general solution that is a bit more complex:

```
def expandpath(path_pattern) -> Iterable[Path]:
    p = Path(path_pattern).expanduser()
    parts = p.parts[p.is_absolute():]
    return Path(p.root).glob(str(Path(*parts)))

expandpath("~/python*/*.py")
```

note-2: the above function **fails** (`IndexError: tuple index out of range`) with these degenerate paths: `''`, `'.'`, `'/'`

Comment: This seems to work as long as the wildcards are in the `name` portion of the path as in my example.  In the general case, would it be better using `expanduser()` and then iterating over `parts()` as suggested by @MadPhysicist, or `parents()` then doing a merge?

Comment: @Omegaman good call. Thankfully iterating and merging is not necessary. I've appended a slightly more complicated version to my original solution that solves this generally for relative and absolute paths with globs at many levels.

Comment: The 2nd solution is good, it's just funny that this isn't implemented in ``pathlib`` to start with, when I would expect it to be a very common use case of globs... does anyone care to open a feature request?

Comment: Booooo pathlib!

Answer (score 10):

[`pathlib.Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) does not support absolute (non-relative) path patterns, but [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) does:

```
from glob import glob
from pathlib import Path

paths = [Path(p) for p in glob('/foo/*/bar')]
```

Or in connection with `Path.expanduser`:

```
paths = [Path(p) for p in glob(str(Path('~/.bash*').expanduser()))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I *really* wanted the inline expansion.  It wasn't as easy as I thought it'd be.

Anyhow, here's what I've got.  Only trivialy tested, but let me know where it falls down for you and I'll edit it.

```
def expand_pathglobs(pathparts, basepaths=None):
    # Logic:
    # 0. Argue with a Path(str).parts and optional ['/start','/dirs'].
    # 1. for each basepath, expand out pathparts[0] into "expandedpaths"
    # 2. If there are no more pathparts, expandedpaths is the result.
    # 3. Otherwise, recurse with expandedpaths and the remaining pathparts.
    # eg: expand_pathglobs('/tmp/a*/b*')
    #   --> /tmp/a1/b1
    #   --> /tmp/a2/b2

    if isinstance(pathparts, str) or isinstance(pathparts, Path):
        pathparts = Path(pathparts).parts

    if basepaths == None:
        return expand_pathglobs(pathparts[1:], [Path(pathparts[0])])
    else:
        assert pathparts[0] != '/'

    expandedpaths = []
    for p in basepaths:
        assert isinstance(p, Path)
        globs = p.glob(pathparts[0])
        for g in globs:
            expandedpaths.append(g)

    if len(pathparts) > 1:
        return expand_pathglobs(pathparts[1:], expandedpaths)

    return expandedpaths
```